# Why is my custom model not running on the coral micro edge tpu?

Tags: google-coral, edge-tpu

I followed the documentation on how to run a model on the edgetpu (https://coral.ai/docs/reference/micro/tensorflow/#tflm-interpreter) however when I try to invoke the interpreter the coral micro stops functioning. The edgetpu compiler compiled my model with no errors into an edgetpu model, and the non edge tpu model runs fine. I have no clue what to change.

Is it a problem with the op resolver?

```
// Copyright 2022 Google LLC
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include "libs/tensorflow/utils.h"
#include "examples/tflm_hello_world/hello_world_model.h"
#include "libs/base/led.h"
#include "libs/base/timer.h"
#include <climits>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "libs/tpu/edgetpu_manager.h"
#include "libs/tpu/edgetpu_op.h"
#include "third_party/freertos_kernel/include/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "third_party/freertos_kernel/include/task.h"
#include "third_party/tflite-micro/tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h"
#include "third_party/tflite-micro/tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h"
#include "third_party/tflite-micro/tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_error_reporter.h"
#include "third_party/tflite-micro/tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
#include "libs/base/filesystem.h"
// Runs a tiny TFLM model on the M7 core, NOT on the Edge TPU, which simply
// outputs sine wave values over time in the serial console.
//
// For more information about this model, see:
// https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/tree/main/tensorflow/lite/micro/examples
//
// To build and flash from coralmicro root:
//    bash build.sh
//    python3 scripts/flashtool.py -e tflm_hello_world

const int test_data[] = { 
4,4,9,3,6,8,0,8,7,4,8,2,0,6,6,7,1,2,6,1,9,0,6,8,6,8,8,7,1,3,5,8,9,9,8,6,4,6,1,7,3,2,6,5,5,8,7,6,6,7,3,9,2,5,2,1,5,1,3,8,7,6,9,6,2,2,7,4,0,9,2,4,5,8,7,5,8,7,0,8,8,3,0,1,3,0,2,7,9,6,5,4,3,9,2,0,1,8,0,3,5,2,5,9,4,4,7,4,2,6,7,5,7,3,7,6,8,9,2,7,1,3,9,7,1,0,3,8,0,5,3,2,9,2,3,2,1,1,2,1,0,1,8,7,4,0,4,9,1,5,4,3,8,0,7,5,3,2,0,2,3,1,6,2,5,7,0,9,3,3,2,2,8,6,5,6,2,6,1,2,4,7,8,8,3,3,8,9,0,7,5,6,9,1,5,0,6,1,3,0,8,3,9,2,9,9,7,7,7,1,9,1,5,3,8,0,5,1,9,2,0,0,6,9,4,2,9,2,7,2,1,1,3,4,0,5,8,8,7,3,
};

// const float test_data[] = { 
// 0.22768896476796524,0.2047959025298774,0.21628123544932484,0.2037094521185783,0.2047959025298774,0.193388173211237,0.17049511097314915,0.18190284029178955,0.1590097780537017,0.1590097780537017,0.1590097780537017,0.16940866056185008,0.13619431941642093,0.09040819494024523,0.0,0.3295048890268508,0.5228930622380878,0.7723110352320348,0.6476020487350613,0.5114077293186404,0.39702002172900824,0.4199130839670961,0.3741269594909204,0.3741269594909204,0.35239795126493867,0.2952040974701226,0.28379636815148224,0.2494179729939469,0.2151171814372187,0.21628123544932484,0.2390966940866056,0.26198975632469346,0.28379636815148224,0.32841843861555176,0.3409902219462983,0.4210771379792022,0.5,0.5904081949402452,0.7047959025298773,0.8054477727766568,0.9313208132857365,1.0,0.8741269594909203,0.7379326400744994,0.7150395778364116,0.6578457240415956,0.3752910135030265,0.12470898649697346,0.0,0.011485332919447462,0.03321434114542915,0.06751513270215738,0.07900046562160484,0.06751513270215738,0.09149464535154431,0.06867918671426354,0.056107403383516996,0.056107403383516996,0.07900046562160484,0.10189352785969269,0.8333965844402277,0.8333965844402277,0.8473434535104364,0.8195445920303606,0.8333965844402277,0.8329222011385199,0.8333965844402277,0.8329222011385199,0.8333965844402277,0.8329222011385199,0.8467741935483871,0.8467741935483871,0.8752371916508539,0.8752371916508539,0.9443074003795067,0.9860531309297913,1.0,0.7637571157495257,0.27751423149905124,0.04127134724857685,0.0,0.19392789373814043,0.22229601518026565,0.15265654648956356,0.12485768500948767,0.11091081593927894,0.11091081593927894,0.09743833017077799,0.08358633776091082,0.11091081593927894,0.13870967741935483,0.1666034155597723,0.18055028462998102,0.1944022770398482,0.18055028462998102,0.22229601518026565,0.3057874762808349,0.4306451612903226,0.47239089184060723,0.444022770398482,0.6663187855787476,0.8195445920303606,0.9164136622390892,0.9860531309297913,0.9994307400379506,0.9722011385199241,0.930360531309298,0.902561669829222,0.8891840607210626,0.9031309297912713,0.902561669829222,0.8752371916508539,0.8886148007590133,0.8746679316888045,0.8886148007590133,0.8886148007590133,0.8746679316888045,0.8607210626185958,0.8473434535104364,0.8467741935483871,0.7136757350250091,0.695498353055996,0.7157496645114066,0.7067219714529706,0.9636452360619739,0.9818226180309869,0.9839575454434549,0.9657801634744418,0.9546175430035378,0.7954129559594973,0.7339270464804196,0.7409418079785287,0.7045870440405027,0.679455898499451,0.7954129559594973,0.34982310601439554,0.18854458948395755,0.24094180797852874,0.14316213248749543,0.0,0.15225082347200194,0.2318531169940222,0.22276442600951568,0.4365011589605953,0.5453824569964622,0.5272050750274491,0.5544711479809686,0.4637062339880444,0.4476027815054288,0.4385140905209223,0.3931316335244602,0.4022203245089667,0.42039770647797975,0.4294863974624863,0.4385140905209223,0.4476027815054288,0.5705136025375137,0.6543247529583994,0.6976332804684641,0.4476027815054288,0.7681468830059778,0.8861778699524216,0.9909113090154935,0.9364401610345249,0.8589727949249726,0.9022203245089667,1.0,0.9113090154934732,0.7863242649749909,0.6976332804684641,0.6613395144565085,0.6885445894839576,0.6613395144565085,0.7136757350250091,0.8044406490179334,0.7772355739904844,0.6976332804684641,0.679455898499451,0.6976332804684641,0.6976332804684641,0.03571894784935709,0.0494093074864565,0.05774753606161478,0.05774753606161478,0.12463285686312904,0.1337543241302787,0.1497454474251028,0.1406076626852033,0.13146987794530382,0.08057568043861367,0.07600678806866393,0.06608576463677306,0.015175249657333072,0.0,0.10488871483584622,0.17175771816461066,0.29492200248025585,0.40813262841851056,0.4841557339599243,0.5373180601788395,0.5570458847333725,0.5844755564258207,0.5927648325827296,0.5904803863977547,0.5707525618432218,0.5973337249526793,0.5904803863977547,0.5098883884863912,0.5107368970693819,0.5410384439657986,0.5844755564258207,0.6527804973565694,0.6962339272893414,0.7333888127406827,0.750815873637491,0.780546308987664,0.8002578160694471,0.8337086352065792,0.7728118269042491,0.7045232034462502,0.8314078715488545,0.9303407088310163,1.0,0.943182559885125,0.7393773252398669,0.5510410547614385,0.3069806148423732,0.29182168265778996,0.28349977155538153,0.274361986815482,0.20063964493179295,0.16720514326741073,0.14436068141766203,0.15431433979505255,0.19607075256184323,0.1983551987468181,0.16035180471248614,0.14892957378761176,0.14207623523268717,0.14517655505515306,
// };

namespace coralmicro {
namespace{

uint64_t startTime;
uint64_t endTime;
uint64_t inferenceTime;

int inference_count = 0;
const int kInferencesPerCycle = 1000;

// An area of memory to use for input, output, and intermediate arrays.
constexpr int kTensorArenaSize = 8 * 1024 * 1024;
STATIC_TENSOR_ARENA_IN_SDRAM(tensor_arena, kTensorArenaSize);


[[noreturn]] void Main() {

  coralmicro::TimerInit();
  LedSet(Led::kStatus, true);

  //-----------------------------TURN ON EDGETPU---------------------------
  auto tpu_context = EdgeTpuManager::GetSingleton()->OpenDevice();
  if (!tpu_context) {
    printf("ERROR: Failed to get EdgeTpu context\r\n");
  }
  //-----------------------------END TURN ON EDGETPU---------------------------

  //---------------------------------LOAD MODEL-----------------------------
  constexpr char kModelPath[] = "/models/model_V4_QUANTIZED_edgetpu.tflite";

  std::vector<uint8_t> model;
  if (!LfsReadFile(kModelPath, &model)) {
    printf("ERROR: Failed to load %s\r\n", kModelPath);
    vTaskSuspend(nullptr);
  }
  //---------------------------END LOAD MODEL--------------------------------

  //---------------------------OP RESOLVER---------------------------------
  tflite::MicroErrorReporter error_reporter;
  tflite::MicroMutableOpResolver<10> resolver;
  resolver.AddQuantize();
  resolver.AddDequantize();
  resolver.AddDepthwiseConv2D();
  resolver.AddConv2D();
  resolver.AddExpandDims();
  resolver.AddReshape();
  resolver.AddMean();
  resolver.AddSoftmax();
  resolver.AddFullyConnected();
  resolver.AddLogistic();
  resolver.AddCustom(kCustomOp, RegisterCustomOp());
  //-------------------------END OP RESOLVER--------------------------------

  //-------------------------INTERPRETER INIT------------------------------

  tflite::MicroInterpreter interpreter(tflite::GetModel(model.data()),
                                     resolver, tensor_arena,
                                     kTensorArenaSize, &error_reporter);

  if (interpreter.AllocateTensors() != kTfLiteOk) {
    printf("ERROR: AllocateTensors() failed\r\n");
    vTaskSuspend(nullptr);
  }

  auto* input_tensor = interpreter.input_tensor(0);
  auto* output_tensor = interpreter.output_tensor(0);
  //----------------------END INTERPRETER INIT-----------------------------

  //------------------------START INFERENCE LOOP---------------------------
  while (true){

    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
    //std::memcpy(tflite::GetTensorData<uint8_t>(input_tensor), test_data, sizeof(test_data));
    for (int i = 0; i < 240; i++) {
      input_tensor->data.uint8[i] = test_data[i];
      printf("\r\n progress: %d", i);
      //printf("\r\n %d", input_tensor->data.uint8[i]);
    }

    //-------------------------------INVOKE INTERPRETER-------------------------------
    startTime = coralmicro::TimerMicros();
    if (interpreter.Invoke() != kTfLiteOk) {
      printf("ERROR: Invoke() failed\r\n");
    }
    endTime = coralmicro::TimerMicros();
    inferenceTime = endTime-startTime;
    printf("inference time: %u \r\n ", (unsigned int)(inferenceTime));

    //-------------------------------END INVOKE INTERPRETER-------------------------------


    printf("inference time: %u \r\n ", (unsigned int)(inferenceTime));
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(10000));
  }
  //---------------------------END INFERENCE LOOP-------------------------------------
}
} //namespace 
} //namespace coralmicro

extern "C" void app_main(void* param) {
  (void)param;
  coralmicro::Main();
}
```

After flashing I tried reading the results with a serial monitor, the monitor opens however there is no output. Changing just the model to the same model that is not compiled on the edgetpu shows the expected output on the serial monitor.